# Using iFrames, how to stop target=_blank

Tags: iframe, target

I'm using an iframe to a separate domain that I don't own, but I would like the links to stay inside my iframe but they use target=_blank

It doesn't appear to be possible from what I've searched but thought I would ask before giving up

Answer (score 0):

You could in theory use some JavaScript from your parent page to hook into the child page, with some psudocode like `$("#iframeID").contents()` to get the frame contents then using something like `$("a").target = "_self"` you'll need to look up jQuery for the the exact syntax though.

The catch is that this wouldn't work on a cross domain unless [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)